# Dataframe exported to CSV turns out different with data appearing in different columns then originally was

Tags: python, csv, pandas, export-to-excel

I'm trying to read a CSV as a dataframe, then sort by column and subsequently output the sorted dataframe into a new CSV. However, the problem is that my output CSV looks nothing like the sorted dataframe with data being moved to wrong columns etc etc. I suspect that the problem lies with the data as some columns are made up of long strings and might have special characters - this is because when I stripped out certain columns, the steps I took below does work. I have tried to export and reimport the dataframe in both dictionary and pickle format and it works perfectly.

First I read in a CSV file and then sort by a column (The csv files I used can be downloaded in the comment below (<100kb in size)

```
df = pd.read_csv("database.csv",encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
sorteddf = df.sort_values(by="All Comment Score")
```

[This show how the dataframe looks after sorting (What I want)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qnHB.png)

Then I store my dataframe in a new CSV file and read that new CSV as a new dataframe:

```
sorteddf.to_csv("test.csv")
newdf = pd.read_csv("test.csv",encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

However, when I read the newly outputed CSV file as a new dataframe, the columns and the data appear to be a mess:
[This shows how the dataframe imported from the output CSV actually looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kriPo.png)

I would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on my problem and point me in the right direction!

Comment: The original CSV and the outputed CSV file can be found at http://www.filedropper.com/files_10 (very small file size, less than 100kb)

I have to post it down here because I have less than 10 reputation points!

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the unnamed column?

Try using

`sorteddf.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)`

This tells pandas not to output the inbuilt index column (most of the time you don't care about this)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking the time to reply me.

I tried your method and it [the reloaded dataframe looks like this](http://imgur.com/a/YSmTk). However, if you see look at index 8, the "author" column instead of showing me the author's name has a hyper textlink there instead Another example would be under the "Current Comment Score", row 8 shows me a product name.

Comment: My best guess as to what is happening is that when writing the dataframe to the CSV file... some of the text strings are being split up into additional columns, thus pushing all subsequent data "one column" to the right

Answer (score 0):

You have decoding/encoding issues. Your encoding is not in "ISO" its in 'latin-1'. Its hard to fix this unless you figure out why you are reading in your data like this.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking the time to reply me.

I'm 100% certain that those rows do not exists in the original dataframe because I visually checked the data in excel (it's only 50 or so rows) and because the data was collected using a short python script I wrote.

If you do not mind, you could try downloading the file I used at filedropper.com/files_10 (<100kb). Under original CSV you can see that the data aligns with their columns nicely. But after you sort and write to CSV, you can see that the data no longer aligns with their columns.

Comment: You have decoding/encoding issues. Your encoding is not in "ISO" its in 'latin-1'. Its hard to fix this unless you figure out why you are reading in your data like this.

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I managed to fix my script and read the csv as utf-8 and now everything works great!

Comment: Awesome. I updated my answer in case other people run into this problem. Be sure to vote as the accepted answer.